# Como eu poderia inverter a forma que um foreach percorre o objeto?

Tags: c#, winforms

Código a seguir:

```
foreach(Control objCtrl in groupBox.Controls)
{
    if (objCtrl is NumericTextBox)
    {
        int i = objCtrl.Text.Length;
        MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(objCtrl.Text) || objCtrl.Text == "0,00")
        {
            this.exibeNotificacaoCampoVazio(objCtrl, "Atenção", "O esse campo não pode ser vazio");
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: além de não ser apropriado, se você sabe o tamanho fixo da coleção, faria mais sentido usar um for simples com decremento

Comment: E mesmo assim... por que você quer fazer isso? se a ideia é percorrer todos os itens, qual a diferença da ordem? Explique melhor o seu cenário, pois parece que você está focando em uma solução que não é o tratamento do seu problema.

Comment: Ele esta percorrendo umas Textbox ai exibe uma menssagem em cima dela. Explicando de uma forma simplificada só queris saber como inverter a forma que ele está exibindo a mensagem, deu certo!

Answer (score 5):

Com o método de extensão `IEnumerable<T>.Reverse`

Exemplo:

```
// using System.Collections.Generic;
// using System.Linq;
IEnumerable<int> list = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };

foreach (var item in list.Reverse())
{
    Console.Write(item + " ");
} // saída: 3 2 1
```